# Ручное освобождение памяти

Tags: сборщик-мусора, память, классы, c#

Будет-ли считаться подобная конструкция полноценным освобождением памяти или я наивный глупый говнокодер?

```
List<string> lst = new List<String>();
lst.Add("asdasd");
ActiveForm.Text = lst[0].ToString();

lst = null;
GC.Collect();
ActiveForm.Text = lst[0].ToString();
```

При выполнении такого кода вылетает ошибка о том что

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: Ошибку я специально вызвал

Comment: Воспринимайте ссылки в C# как shared_ptr в C++. Все, что вам может хотеться сделать - это вызвать Dispose(), если он есть.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В подобной ситуации вам вообще ничего не нужно делать. Очистка памяти, занимаемой переменной lst произойдет в фоне, и программисту не нужно прилагать для этого какие бы то ни было усилия. В принципе, вызов GC.Collect() инициирует сборку мусора, но вызывать его для освобождения переменной List<string> - это стрельба из пушки по воробьям. В вызове этого метода **почти никогда нет необходимости**. В редких случаях, при обработке очень больших объемов данных может возникнуть потребность в вызове этого метода, но вообще делать это стоит крайне редко и осторожно.

Теперь пару слов о вашем коде:

1. Исключение NullReferenceException (Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта) вылетает не из-за того, что вы вызвали GC.Collect, а из-за того, что вы собственноручно присвоили переменной lst значение null
2. Для освобождения памяти не нужно присваивать переменным null. Еще раз повторю - сборщик мусора все сделает сам.
3. В любом случае сборщик мусора не станет освобождать память из под lst в тот момент, когда вы явно вызываете GC.Collect() поскольку после вызова GC.Collect  вы по-прежнему используете переменную lst, а следовательно, в памяти на нее остаются ссылки.

З.Ы. Почитайте 21 главу из книги CLR via C# Джеффри Рихтера. Там как раз подробно рассказывается про сборку мусора.

З.З.Ы. Если представить, то, что вы описали в комментарии, то lst = null не будет панацеей для освобождения памяти. В общем случае, если ваш класс работает с некими ресурсами, то он должен реализовывать интерфейс IDisposable, а в методе Dispose вашего класса будет необходимо описать логику освобождения ресурсов.

выглядеть такое освобождение будет примерно так:

```
var myDisposable = new MyDisposable();
try 
{
    // something
}
finally 
{
    if(myDisposable != null)
        myDisposable.Dispose();
}
```

Либо так (эквивалентно приведенному выше коду)

```
using(var myDisposable = new myDisposable())
{ 
    // something
}
```

Помимо этого не помешает также определить финализатор для вашего класса на тот случай, если вы забудете освободить ресурсы. В финализаторе тоже нужно описать логику освобождения ресурсов (для этого может быть достаточно вызова уже определенного вами метода Dispose) В этом случае освобождение ресурсов будет осуществлено при сборке мусора.

Если же ваш код просто есть много-много памяти, и сборщик мусора не очень успевает ее возвращать, то тогда, возможно, есть смысл попробовать использовать GC.Collect

А вот само по себе lst = null не сигнализирует сборщику мусора о необходимости "собрать" lst, поскольку  сборщик мусора руководствуется наличием/отсутствием ссылок на переменную. А таковые могут оставатьися и после присвоения lst значения null

Comment: Эхх. Чуть-чуть опоздал. :)

Comment: Я не ожидал что вы ответите конкретно по этому примеру :) Если представить что lst это сферический объект в вакууме, экземпляр моего сферического класса, который засранец работает с потоками и в при выполнении, в геометрической прогрессии заполняет всю свободную память ПК. Ну, создаётся миллион экземпляров класса объёмом по 100 Кб, и мне хочется часть из них в определённый момент времени освобождать, а некоторые из них оставлять в работе. Грубовато, но я самоучка, другими словами не умею :)

Comment: обновил ответ. Если вкратце, то простое lst = null пользы не принесет

Comment: В случае если вам требуется поймать исключения, то используйте конструкцию
try 
{
    // something
}
catch
{
    // esxeption
}
finally 
{
    if(myDisposable != null)
        myDisposable.Dispose();
}
, а если исключения несущественны, то тогда
using(var myDisposable = new myDisposable())
{ 
    // something
}

Answer (score 2):

Данный код скорее всего будет нагружать систему, так как сборщик мусора очищает систему не только от твоего объекта, ссылка на который находится в переменной lst. Советую использовать GC тогда, когда это действительно необходимо, а такой необходимости в твоем коде нет. И вообще, "оставь Кесарю кесарево".

Естественно ошибка будет вылетать, так как, даже без сборки мусора, ты очистил ссылку на объект (lst = null)

Comment: Вот здесь можно почитать.
[When to call GC.Collect()][1]


  [1]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Comment: инструкция lst = null освобождает память или просто ссылку удаляет, а память остаётся занятой?

Comment: Просто очищает ссылку